# How to increase letter spacing when using unicode-math range feature?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, unicode-math, kerning, math-fonts

Using the package unicode-math and compiling with xelatex, one may use `\setmathfont[range= ... ,Scale=MatchLowercase]{ ... }` to change the italic and upright math letters. However, there are usually some kerning problems. For example, superscripts being to close to the italic f or the bottom hitting a preceding parenthesis.  How can I import a range of glyphs and increase the space applied before or after them?
I searched `unicode-math` package manual for some option similar to `Scale` dealing with this but did not manage to find one.